# Why does GCP cloud debugger only support Go 1.9 and below?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, remote-debugging, google-cloud-debugger

The docs for the [GCP cloud debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/go) has a prominent warning to set up a Go agent:

> Cloud Debugger only works with Go 1.9 and lower.

I was curious: is there a technical reason for using Go 1.9 or lower? It's not terribly often I see constraints for version X or *lower*.